# Wordpress Error while developing a plugin -"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just started learning wordpress plugin development and got this error when I access the my plugin menu from admin.

Here is the code: importer.php

```
//*************** Admin function ***************
function oscimp_admin() {
    include('importer_admin.php');
}

function oscimp_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page("OSCommerce Product Display", "OSCommerce Product Display", 1, "OSCommerce Product Display", "oscimp_admin");
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'oscimp_admin_actions');
```

importer_admin.php

```
<div class="wrap">
<?php    echo "<h2>" . __( 'OSCommerce Product Display Options', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h2>"; ?>

<form name="oscimp_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="oscimp_hidden" value="Y">
    <?php    echo "<h4>" . __( 'OSCommerce Database Settings', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h4>"; ?>
    <p><?php _e("Database host: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbhost" value="<?php echo $dbhost; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: localhost" ); ?></p>
    <p><?php _e("Database name: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbname" value="<?php echo $dbname; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: oscommerce_shop" ); ?></p>
    <p><?php _e("Database user: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbuser" value="<?php echo $dbuser; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: root" ); ?></p>
    <p><?php _e("Database password: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbpwd" value="<?php echo $dbpwd; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: secretpassword" ); ?></p>
    <hr />
    <?php    echo "<h4>" . __( 'OSCommerce Store Settings', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h4>"; ?>
    <p><?php _e("Store URL: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_store_url" value="<?php echo $store_url; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: http://www.yourstore.com/" ); ?></p>
    <p><?php _e("Product image folder: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_prod_img_folder" value="<?php echo $prod_img_folder; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: http://www.yourstore.com/images/" ); ?></p>


    <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Update Options', 'oscimp_trdom' ) ?>" />
    </p>
</form>
</div>
```

Any one can figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is fourth parameter.
I have removed the spaces from the fourth parameter with _ and it works.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 6):

The actual tutorial can be find [HERE](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/). And it should work with 2.9.2 version of Wordpress, at least it works for me. But, when I try to run the code of the tutorial with version 3.1 it give me the same error. But as mention by Avinash the line

```
add_options_page(“OSCommerce Product Display”, “OSCommerce Product Display”, 1, “OSCommerce Product Display”, “oscimp_admin”);
```

Should be replace with

```
add_options_page(“OSCommerce Product Display”, “OSCommerce Product Display”, 1, “OSCommerce_Product_Display”, “oscimp_admin”);
```

and then it works properly. Hope it helps some one.

**UPDATE**:

As rightly stated by *Francisco Corrales* at below comment you may consider to Deactivate the Plugin & Activate it again if you are not seeing the changes.

Comment: Terrible tutorial. This change made no difference for me.

Comment: Please make it more clear, I spend 5 minutes starring at those lines.  It is important to add that you need to Deactive the plugin, and the activate it back.

Comment: Thanks Francisco Corrales. Added your comment at the answer. BTW may I know which WP version you are using for this plugin?

Comment: I was using 3.8 Wordpress. +1 cause you listen to me.

Answer (score 3):

One possible cause of this error is actually registering admin menus on `admin_init` action hook, instead of `admin_menu`. This is not the case here, but it is good to share this information, since it took me hours to figure that out.

So always register your menus like this (and remove spaces or any other non alphanumeric characters from the unique slug - the **4th** parameter of the function `add_options_page()` ):

Initially

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'your_function');
```

and then (check first if function exists)

```
if (!function_exists('your_function')) {
    function your_function() {
        add_options_page(__("Option page name","your-text-domain"), __("Option page name","your-text-domain"), 'manage_options', 'your-page-unique-slug', 'other_function');
    }
}
```

Note the usage of `__()` function instead of directly placing the titles - it is necessary for internationalization of your plug-in (and it displays the quoted text if there are no internationalization files).

Answer (score 1):

On Wordpress 3.6.1 not even underscores work anymore. The function should now be:

```
function oscimp_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page("OSCommerce Product Display", "OSCommerce Product Display", 1, "OSCommerceProductDisplay", "oscimp_admin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write your importer_admin.php file code inside oscimp_admin() function or use php file_get_contents function.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to change the 4th parameter in add_options_page with basename(_*FILE*_); should be the same value with "importer.php" in your case. I don't know exactly what it should be changed to, but it's work!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Forth parameter is Unique name, and for any Unique identifier it should contain space, That's the issue :)