# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page without any change

Tags: wordpress, ftp, admin

I am working on Wordpress and I completed my project locally. I then moved it to my live server and did not change anything, I just made changes in the config file (database name, username and password).

Now my site is working fine on the front-end but I can't get access to the admin panel as every time it gives me the error message:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Google searches indicate that most of the errors occurred due to a change in the prefix but in my case its the same as on local. Also, the permissions of my directories are 755 and that of files is 644 but still am facing the same issue.

How might I go about fixing this?

Comment: There is another solution for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224084/wordpress-error-while-developing-a-plugin-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissio?rq=1

Comment: Another solution - If your table prefix is not **wp**,but i.e. **blabla**, then in **blabla_usermeta** table, find user id, and set **blabla_capabilities** (instead of **wp_capabilities** ) value to **a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}** and **blabla_user_level** value to **10**

Comment: Great question; useful best answer. Far better than the incoherent threads on wordpress.org: Suggest moving this question to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where it can have a better life.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Have you changed the prefix of your database tables? I'm 90% sure, that this is your problem.

The thing is that WordPress uses the `$table_prefix` variable for forming the option and usermeta keys names, where it's storing the roles and capabilities information. So once you change the prefix, but don't update your db, you get this error. Here's how to fix it - execute this SQL command through phpMyAdmin, or a different interface for interacting with your DB(you can do it with PHP as well):

```
UPDATE `{%TABLE_PREFIX%}usermeta` SET `meta_key` = replace(`meta_key`, '{%OLD_TABLE_PREFIX%}', '{%NEW_TABLE_PREFIX%}') WHERE option_name like '{%OLD_TABLE_PREFIX%}%';
UPDATE `{%TABLE_PREFIX%}options` SET `option_name` = replace(`option_name`, '{%OLD_TABLE_PREFIX%}', '{%NEW_TABLE_PREFIX%}') WHERE option_name like '{%OLD_TABLE_PREFIX%}%';
```

Where:

- `{%TABLE_PREFIX%}` is your current `$table_prefix`(as set in `wp-config.php`)
- `{%OLD_TABLE_PREFIX%}` is your previous `$table_prefix`
- `{%NEW_TABLE_PREFIX%}` is your new(current) `$table_prefix` - it will most-likely be the same as your `{%TABLE_PREFIX%}`.

So if your old `$table_prefix` was `wp_test_` and your new one is `wp_`, you would do this query:

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_key` = replace(`meta_key`, 'wp_test_', 'wp_') WHERE option_name like 'wp_test_%';
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_name` = replace(`option_name`, 'wp_test_', 'wp_') WHERE option_name like 'wp_test_%';
```

---

EDIT: As @Francisco Corrales noted, if you are having troubles accessing an admin page that you created(if you don't write PHP, this is not your case), you can check out this link: [Wordpress Error while developing a plugin -"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224084/wordpress-error-while-developing-a-plugin-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissio?rq=1)

---

EDIT 2: Thanks to @Kasper Souren for suggesting that you might want to add a WHERE clause to the options UPDATE query. If you don't do this, you might accidentally update some other option inadvertently. I have added the WHERE clause to all sample queries. If you are sure you don't need it, then feel free to remove it at your own risk.

Comment: no i havent changed the prefix. the prefix on local as well as live is bt_

Comment: How did you import your DB? Did you make any changes to it?

Comment: i import in the normal ways as usual. export it from local and then import it on live. made no change at all

Comment: That's pretty strange. This message usually means a problem with permissions - and the fact that you are redirected to profile.php also supports that(since users with least access get redirected to their profile). I'm not sure what went wrong. You made a DB export/import, correct? Can you try doing it again(delete the tables that you created before and import over the clean database)?

Comment: i did it 3 times but still facing the same problem

Comment: Can you look in your DB and check the following tables: `{$table_prefix}options` - look for an entry with `option_name` similar to `{$table_prefix}roles`. Then look in `{$table_prefix}usermeta` and look for entry with `meta_key` similar to `{$table_prefix}capabilities`. `$table_prefix` is what you have in your `wp-config.php`. If you can't find those entries, or they have the wrong `option_name` or `meta_key` - then fix them and try again. If you find them, paste the content here.

Comment: i reached to the solution thanx for your help. infact the problem was that after updating, one row was not effected which remaind the old prefix, strange but true so i manually changed it and i got my result. salut and thanx

Comment: there is another solution for this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224084/wordpress-error-while-developing-a-plugin-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissio?rq=1

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales - not exactly related. The OP of the topic you linked to can't access a single page in the admin and the current OP wasn't able to access any of the pages in the admin.

Comment: Yeah, not exactly, but many people may come here first and spend a lot of time, please add a note to link that question, could save time for other people.

Comment: Updated - but I still don't think a person with the other issue would be reading this page - this one clearly says "without any change" in the title - and the description is about the user moving the site from a local to live environment and not tweaking with the code.

Comment: It could be good to add `WHERE option_name like 'wp_%'` in case of the prefix occurs in the options.

Comment: Many many thanks. It's work great!!!

Comment: Please fix your first update query instead of adding an EDIT2... if people execute the first query without reading all the answer they could already be in trouble.

Comment: @iBobo done! A bit late, but better late than never, right? Thank you for the suggestion - it is a valid point.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is not with permission on directories. The fact that you see a "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" message means three things :

1. you are trying to access an admin page directly but not through wp-admin (so please indicate which admin page you are trying to access),
2. you are already logged in (otherwise you would be redirected to /wp-admin) and
3. the area you are trying to access is reserved for a higher level of user (so you might be connecting with an editor account whereas the area is only accessible to administrators).

Can you tell us if your local database and the online database are the same? Can you log in properly before you see this message?

Comment: i am logging properly by enter username and password but when i click the login button it goes to profile.php page and the display me the message that i mentioned above and also i am the top level admin

Comment: Using WordPress MU (multisite)? did you use the same wp-config.php and changed the credentials or did you use another wp-config.php?