# Wordpress error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" from http-https

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress 4.1 and I changed from http to https, then when I tried to login I am getting an error that

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

So could any one help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page without any change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815461/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-without-any-change)

Comment: I have this issue to, switching from http to https, some plugins perhaps that might have caused this. Not sure..

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too,

backup your .htaccess file, and use this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

then, in wp-config remove the https back to http

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
```

---

this should get you back to the dashboard, and you can start working on it again.